# Why is Chrome not able to display Graphics and images when Safari is able to?

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, rstudio, knitr

1. I work on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) running OS X El Capitan.
2. I am using the latest version of Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit).
3. I have created an **ioslides HTML file using knitr on RStudio** http://rpubs.com/cjagtap/capstone_glim which runs smoothly on Safari but not on Chrome.

### `

```
title: "MWE_ioslides"
author: "Chaitanya Jagtap"
output:
ioslides_presentation:
```

### dev: pdf

##Plot Cars

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

`

In the **YAML header** in am using **dev: pdf**.
I am using **dev='tikz' as a chunk option** and **would not like to set it to 'png' or 'svg'** as 'png' results in blurred images and 'svg' increases the html size manyfold.

Can anyone please let me know why, is there anything I can do to fix the problem?

[Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtWXZ.png)

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Comment: http://rpubs.com/cjagtap/capstone_glim displays just fine for me in Chrome for Windows.

Comment: Hi Eric J. Thank you for checking. Did you try going through the first few slides say first 5. The first slide is displaying correctly.

Comment: As far as I know, PDF is not a file format that browsers usually support for images. However, `dev="tikz"` produces PDFs. The reason why it works for some users and not for others may be different plugins or settings for displaying PDFs. Though I see the beauty of `tikz` graphics I would recommend using PNG. You should be able to reduce the blurryness by choosing a higher resolution. Please add a reproducable example to the question to allow for more specific help.

Comment: Added a MWE, when this MWE was run on a Windows 7 machine in RStudio the preview as well as Chrome could not display the plot, so I am not sure whom to point the finger at!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be that it's because your files are stored in base64. If you store the file in an external location and use the file URL in your  it should display properly on all browsers.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, Thank you for your response. I request for more clarity. What I gather from your reply is, I should store the file on say Google Drive and then upload the file?